# Cross-Numbers (not words)!

Tags: knowledge, visual, crosswords, history

Can you solve this Crossword (**Cross-numbers**) with numbers from the given pictures ?

[image]

ACROSS

[image]

DOWN

[image]

Comment: rot13(Vgf nyjnlf gung crefba jvgu gur fhcre pbairavrag hfreanzr!)

Comment: rot13(Ur unf fhccbegrq zr znal n gvzrf. V hfr bgure hfref anzrf gbb! Gunax lbh.)

Comment: rot13(Ybir vg! Hfre vapyhfvba vf nyjnlf sha)

Comment: just saw my previous identicon here! thanks and +1ed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've found the answers

> [image]

Explanations

> **Across**
>  **2.** 503 = HTTP response indicating the server is not ready to handle requests ("not red E").
>  **3.** 27 = $3^3$
>  **4.** The limit is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which, in degrees is 90.
>  **5.** 1996 = The year Sri Lanka won the Cricket World Cup.
>  **7.** 1977 = The main car used for Mr. Bean was a 1977 British Leyland Mini 1000 
>  (found by Weather Vane).
>  **8.** 82 = The repairer is a plumber, and plumbum = lead , which has atomic number 82 
>  (reasoning revealed by Ak19)
>  **9.** 93 = Height of the Statue of Liberty in metres.
>  **12.** 51131 = User id of Omega Krypton.
>  
>  **Down**
>  **1.** 2019 = July 2nd is the date of next eclipse.
>  **3.** 2012 = Year the world was expected to end according to Mayan prophesy.
>  **5.** 1729 = Famous number associated with Ramanujan.
>  **6.** 666 = The number of the Beast (Revelation).
>  **8.** 888 = In Christian numerology, this is the number associatged to Jesus.
>  **10.** 51, as in *Area* 51.
>  **11.** 31, total number of dots.

Comment: I had got many of them but one digit different for 7. Rot13(gur lrne bs znahsnpgher bs gung Zvav).

Comment: Yes, you've got it. Find the other 3-digit number of Jesus, 72 will get corrected.

Comment: @Ak19 Okay, I've changed it to what I think may be the answer. I still do not fully understand the answer to 8 across.

Comment: The repairer is a plumber, and plumbum  = lead , which has atomic number 82!

Comment: Excellent ....